# Move between buffers of a certain filetype

Tags: gvim, buffers

scenario: I have a bunch of programs that generate output, the programs and output are open in buffers and the programs are one filetype eg .r and the output is another filetype eg .txt

I want to cycle thru buffers for a certain file type, e.g. the txt files. I want a shortcut I can press to immediately move to the next txt file in the bufferlist.

I am not sure why this doesn't work:

```
set wildchar=<Tab> wildmenu wildmode=full
map yy :b<space>*.txt<tab><tab><cr>
```

The error gVim gives: `E93: More than one match for *.txt`

I also tried removing other file types from the buffer list using nobl but as far as I can tell I can only remove them one at a time, I can't do, e.g. `:set nobl *.r`

I realize there are a lot of plugins e.g. fzf, SelectBuf, Editsimilar etc, but I'm doubtful any of them do what I want(?) and I feel there should be a simple solution. I don't want to use autocomplete or rifle thru a list. I just want to move to the next file using a shortcut. I am also aware of args but I am already restricting that list for another reason

related question: [How can I keep a buffer list per window in Vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/321033/how-can-i-keep-a-buffer-list-per-window-in-vim)

Answer (score 0):

in the end i used this BufSel function here: [Easier buffer switching](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching)